# Oracle DATE column - How to convert to UTC

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle 10g table with a `DATE` column type.  I need to compare it in a where clause to a value generated by a script that looks like this:  `TIMESTAMP '2016-05-12 08:00:00.258000 +00:00'`.  I cannot control the generated `TIMESTAMP` part, and when I do:

`RECORDEDTIME >= TIMESTAMP '2016-05-12 08:00:00.258000 +00:00'` it uses the localtime of the `RECORDEDTIME` which means I am 4 hours off.  What function do I call on `RECORDEDTIME` to get it in UTC matching the other value in the `WHERE` clause (i.e. it needs to subtract 4 hours as I'm in EST)

Answer (score 1):

[SYS_EXTRACT_UTC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions167.htm)

```
SQL> SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIMESTAMP '2000-03-28 11:30:00.00 -08:00') FROM DUAL;

SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIMESTAMP'2000-03-2811:30:00.00-08:00')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
28-MAR-00 07.30.00.000000000 PM
```

Comment: I assume it would be rather `WHERE SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(RECORDEDTIME) = TIMESTAMP '2016-05-12 08:00:00.258000 +00:00'`, resp. `WHERE SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CAST(RECORDEDTIME) AS TIMESTAMP) AT '+04:00')= TIMESTAMP '2016-05-12 08:00:00.258000 +00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `where recordtime >= TIMESTAMP '2016-05-12 08:00:00.258000 +00:00' AT LOCAL`